# invalid SUDS envelope

Tags: python, soap, suds

When I try to execute this code:

```
mmurl = 'http://server/_mmwebext/mmwebext.dll?WSDL?server=localhost'
mmclient = Client(mmurl, plugins=[EnvelopeFixer()])
loginResult = mmclient.service[1].Login(u'localhost', u'user', u'pass')
```

the following envelope is created:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://menandmice.com/webservices/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:Login>
         <ns0:server>localhost</ns0:server>
         <ns0:loginName>user</ns0:loginName>
         <ns0:password>pass</ns0:password>
      </ns0:Login>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

which returns:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Invalid command.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <mmfaultdetails>
               <message>Invalid command.</message>
               <errorcode>5001</errorcode>
            </mmfaultdetails>
         </detail>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

but if i change it in soapUI to

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://menandmice.com/webservices/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns0:Login>
         <ns0:server>localhost</ns0:server>
         <ns0:loginName>user</ns0:loginName>
         <ns0:password>pass</ns0:password>
      </ns0:Login>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

it returns successfully

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <LoginResponse xmlns="http://menandmice.com/webservices/">
         <session>UEk6A0UC5bRJ92MqeLiU</session>
      </LoginResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So my question is can i force suds to create the body tag as `<SOAP-ENV:Body>` instead of `<ns1:Body>` or is

I tried this to see if I could change the XML sent over the wire and used wireshark to sniff the traffic and it turned out that it did not change the message being sent. the sending method is being called for sure since I see the print-out in the console

```
class EnvelopeFixer(MessagePlugin):
    def sending(self, context):
        # context is the envelope text
        print type(context)
        context.envelope = context.envelope.upper()
        print context.envelope

        return context
```

I changed EnvelopeFixer to use marshalled instead of sending and that seems to have done the trick

```
class EnvelopeFixer(MessagePlugin):

    def marshalled(self, context):
        root = context.envelope.getRoot()
        envelope = root.getChild("Envelope")
        envelope.getChildren()[1].setPrefix("SOAP-ENV")
        print envelope.getChildren()[1]

        return context
```

So now I have changed the prefix of the body element to comply with what the server requires. JOY!

Comment: Hi davideagle, I used your post to modify my own headers. But I set suds to debug mode for suds.client and I see that although context is changed as per my needs. But suds is still sending what it was earlier. Can you help me?

Comment: Have you removed the previous egg file before running setup.py build and setup.py install again?

Comment: Why do I need to do that? I am using `virtualenv` and then `pip install suds`

Comment: I downloaded the source and made changes to that the EnvelopeFixer mentioned here abow, uninstalled the previous egg file and ran setup.py build && setup.py install. The install does not update the egg file installed since it is the same version as the previous one that's the reason I manually removed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unfortunate that the RPC endpoint does not parse XML correctly. One way to fix would be to add a plugin to your `Client()` that edits the envelope before sending. A [MessagePlugin](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.plugin.MessagePlugin-class.html) gives you the chance to modify the `suds.sax.document.Document` or the message text before sending.

```
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin
class EnvelopeFixer(MessagePlugin):
    def sending(self, context):
        # context is the envelope text
        context.envelope = context.envelope.upper()
        return context

client = Client(..., plugins=[EnvelopeFixer()])
```

Comment: in sending method the context does not seem to be of text but rather of type suds.plugin.MessageContext so I can not access the xml string directly at least

Comment: I am using suds 0.4.0. The plugin is called here: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/browser/trunk/suds/client.py#L635

Comment: I gave this a shot and used wireshark to view the actual message but it turns out it does not change the message sent over the wire when I do context.envelope = context.envelope.upper()

Comment: Thank you, this got me on the right track and I solved the Issue using the marshalled method